# GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get(); is false instead of true

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api

I have implemented the "with google" login button on my site with OAuth 2.0.

I'm having a problem with GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get(); which is supposed to return true when the user is logged in, or false if they are not.

Here is my code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoad" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Déconnexion</a>
    <script>
        function onLoad(){
            gapi.load('auth2', function(){
                gapi.auth2.init();
                GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(signinChanged);
                state = GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get();
            });
        }

        var signinChanged = function (val) {
            console.log('Signin state changed to ', val);
        };

        function signOut(){
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
            window.location.replace('xxxxxxxxxxx.xx/google/login.php');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

With this code here, state is equal to false. But when I execute the command GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get(); in the console, state is equal to true.

All this happens when the user is supposed to be logged in!

How can I make state equal to true instead of false? Because I can't know at the moment if the user is logged in or not...

To clarify, here is what I specifically want to do:

A user logs into my site using the Google Auth button. If the login succeeds, he is redirected to a page that is supposed to be inaccessible if the login fails.

Outside of the login process, I'd like to be able to run a PHP script using Ajax to create a PHP session variable to let the server know that the user is logged in, and to be able to keep them online.

Here we come to my problem:

Currently the connection works and I know how to run a script using ajax. What I don't know how to do is to ask Google if the user is connected to his account or not. Currently, I have the above code that returns "false" no matter if the user is logged in or not. By digging around, I realize that if I ask Google for the login status with a setTimeout() function by setting the timeout to 1 second, I get "true" when the user is logged in and "false" when he is not.

The problem is that this system depends on the user being logged in, since if 1 second is too short to have time to query Google, I'll get a "false" return instead of a "True" return.

How can I make sure that whatever happens, whatever the quality of the connection and therefore the speed of the page loading, I can get the right "true" or "false" value of the user's connection to be able to use it as I want?

Thanks in advance and sorry if it is not clear, it is a simple problem but in a difficult context.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you call `GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get()` in `gapi.load` function, the user is not logged in yet. Because the page has just loaded and user hasn't finished sign-in.

You have to wait for the `signinChanged` function to be called in order to get the correct state.

I think that the following will take you the correct state:

```js
var signinChanged = function(val) {
    console.log('Signin state changed to ', val);
    var state = GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get();
    console.log(state);
};
```

If you need to process some code after signin, you must wait for the `signinChanged` to be called with value [`true`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthissignedinlistenlistener), something like:

```js
var signinChanged = function(val) {
    console.log('Signin state changed to ', val);
    if (val){
        // user is logged in, execute my code here
        callbackToMyCode();
    }
};
```

Comment: This solution does not suit me, see my answer just after this one. I explain my problem better